# Angular 9 service nested http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I need to do a query to 2 separate endpoints to provide the objects needed for my component.

| No | Endpoint | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `/registry/colors` | `{"colors":["red","green","blue","orange"]}` |
| 2 | `/color/{colorName}` | `{"name":"red", "details":["detail1","detail2", "detail3"]}` |

For each color in the colors array, I need to call the color details endpoint and collect all of those color details into an array of Colors.

```js
getColors(): Observable<Color[]> {
  return this.http.get<ColorRegistry>(this.registryUrl).pipe(
    map((registry:ColorRegistry) => registry.colors.concatMap((colorName: string) => {
      return this.http.get<Color>(this.colorUrl+"/"+colorName);
    }))
  )
}
```

I would like the above method to return the following:

```js
[
 {"name":"red", "details":["detail1","detail2", "detail3"]},
 {"name":"green", "details":["detail1","detail2", "detail3"]},
 {"name":"blue", "details":["detail1","detail2", "detail3"]},
 {"name":"orange", "details":["detail1","detail2", "detail3"]}
]
```

Obviously I'm going about this the wrong way, I'm looking for the correct way to do the nested requests with observables.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the right direction.

Try the following changes.

1. Replace the `map` operator with a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`.
2. Use JS `Array#map` and replace each entry in the `colors` array property with the response from the second call.
3. Use `forkJoin` to trigger the requests in parallel and merge the results in the end.

```js
getColors(): Observable<Color[]> {
  return this.http.get<ColorRegistry>(this.registryUrl).pipe(
    switchMap((registry: ColorRegistry) => {
      return forkJoin(
        registry.colors.map((colorName: string) => 
          this.http.get<Color>(`${this.colorUrl}/${colorName}`)
        )
      ) as Observable<Color[]>;    // <— assert type here
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: This is telling me that ```Observable<unknown[]> is not assignable to type 'Observable<Color[]>'. ```

Comment: @Joel: I’ve adjusted the post to add type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
registryUrl = '/registry/colors';

colorUrl(color) {
  return `/color/${color}`;
}

return this.http.get<ColorRegistry>(this.registryUrl).pipe(
  map(registry => from(registry.colors))
  forkJoin(color => this.http.get<Color>(this.colorUrl(color)))
);
```

Comment: This is telling me   Argument of type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Color[]>'.